# Is adding arbitrary precedences to rules that result in a shift/reduce conflict a bad idea?

Tags: parsing, yacc

in a few instances where I'm absolutely not sure how to fix the shift/reduce conflict, is it a bad idea to add an arbitrary precedence before the tokens that cause s/r to resolve them as a fix?

Comment: Silencing warnings does not solve the underlying problem, if that's what you're asking. If you're just introducing random declarations until the warning goes away, then that's a bad idea. If you understand the problem and can prove to yourself that the resolution generated by the precedence declarations does produce a parser for the desired language, then it's fine.

Comment: @rici I do understand it most of the times, but for the times I can't understand why the S/R is occurring and I'm out of things to try, I give a higher precedence to one of the rules that cause S/R and that fixes the issue. Till now, it doesn't seem to have caused a major problem, but I'm wondering just how bad it is. I've seen a few grammars do it, Antlr comes in mind, where the author used predicates and they didn't really know what/why it was needed, but it fixed the issues, and that parser is still used in production.

Comment: I guess it's your call. I wouldn't do it. Certainly, other people do dumb things. And lots of production code has obscure bugs which remain undetected for years until catastrophe strikes, at which point it is discovered that a little more care could have prevented the disaster